# Rally bulk query api with date placeholder

Tags: date, rally, bulk

I am using the Rally bulk query API to pull data from multiple tables. My issue happens when I try to use a placeholder for the Iteration's StartDate and pass it along to a following query same bulk request. i.e.

```
"iteration": "/Iteration?fetch=ObjectID,StartDate&query=(Name = \"Sprint 1\")",
"started": "${iteration.StartDate}",
"other_queries": "...?query=(CreatedDate > $(iteration.StartDate))"
```

The bulk service seems to convert this field to a formatted string. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  I am attempting to use the placeholder to limit other queries by date without making several requests.

It looks like the iteration object comes back with the date correctly, but when it is used as a placeholder it is automatically converted to a string.

```
"started": ["Wed Jan 16 22:00:00 MST 2013"],

"iteration": {
     "Results": [
         ....
         "StartDate": "2013-01-17T05:00:00.000Z",
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, as this functionality is currently implemented, this is expected behavior. The placeholder is converted to a formatted String server-side, so it will be necessary to formulate a similar followup request if the same data is needed in another query.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer. It is an unfortunate limitation. If the return was a unix timestamp rather than a UTC format it would allow for comparisons as a string. It would also remove the need for another roundtrip.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Unfortunately the bulk query toolkit is a Beta project that never really got off the ground. It won't be undergoing further development moving forward and won't be included in  the soon-to-be-released WSAPI 2.0. I'd encourage you to work on porting your query code to the standard query API to maintain compatibility moving forward.